# I'm using Laravel 5 and I'm not being able to migrate my database using php artisan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 but I'm not being able to migrate my database table. I have a macbook pro and I'm using Terminal. I'm using php artisan command:
    php artisan migrate. 
When I execute this command, I get the following error message:       [PDOException]
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused.

I have configured my database.php following the official tutorial videos on laracasts.com. My database.php file looks like the following:
    ...

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
...
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),
...
'connections' => [

'sqlite' => [
'driver' => 'sqlite',
'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
'prefix' => '',
],
....
```

I have read many comments on stackoverflow.com about this issue. Most of them are talking about modifying the ".env" file. The thing is I can't find this file! Which makes me wonder if my installation of Laravel is complete or not! I read that my ".env" file might be overriding my "database.php" file but I can't file the ".env" file!

Comment: The env file is most likely hidden. Do a Google search and find the command to show hidden files. Then, edit your .env file.

Comment: @AshMenhennett. I found that .env file is located inside my "blog" file. I went to Terminal and i wrote: cd blog and then: ls -a. This is command showed me the hidden files like .env file but the question is how can i access hidden files?

Comment: Run ```defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES``` and ```Killall Finder```. Open Finder and you should be able to see the .env file.

Comment: @AshMenhennett. Thanks a lot! I was able to access my .env file and I changed it! Thanks again.

Comment: @AshMenhennett. Now I can migrate my tables! I'm glad for being able to do that. BUT the thing is that I can't understand how official tutorial on laracast.com didn't mention anything about that! It took me 3 days to figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The env file is most likely hidden.

1. Run `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` and `Killall Finder` in Terminal.
2. Open Finder and you should be able to see the .env file.
3. Edit your .env file.